# Website not working properly since moving host. GeoIP Issue

Tags: php, debugging, pear, geoip, maxmind

My website used to work perfectly fine a few months ago.  However, since changing host last month some parts of my website no longer work.

I am very sure the issue is related to GeoIP.  My website requires the GeoIP php extension for it to work correctly.  Both the old and new server have this extension enabled.

I get the following errors on my new server.  Please note that the file "pdf_after_checkout_generator" is a custom made plugin.

***PHP Warning:  include(/usr/share/GeoIP/geoip.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jksastrology/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pdf-after-checkout-generator/pdf_after_checkout_generator.php on line 18***

***PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/usr/share/GeoIP/geoip.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/jksastrology/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pdf-after-checkout-generator/pdf_after_checkout_generator.php on line 18***

***PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function geoip_open() in /home/jksastrology/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pdf-after-checkout-generator/pdf_after_checkout_generator.php on line 20***

I contacted my current host about this issue.  I asked them what the file path is for the GeoIP extension on their server.  They provided the following response (see bottom of post).

I would appreciate answers to the following questions:

1. I am not sure how to implement a solution.  They are saying the file my website requires is not in their GeoIP extension file.  Does this mean I need to install files (within the link they supplied) to my main wordpress site? then point my broken include code to the newly downloaded geoip.inc file?
2. I have no idea what this particular error is about. It is referencing PEAR, and I am not sure why.

***PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/usr/share/GeoIP/geoip.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/jksastrology/public_html/wp-content/plugins/pdf-after-checkout-generator/pdf_after_checkout_generator.php on line 18***

> Hi there,
>
> This would vary depending on what package you have I suspect, the
>   server I checked has the dat file (/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat) present
>   but there is no PHP include file there.
>
> The simplest fix would be to move the PHP dependency into the code
>   base of the application rather than relying on a globally shared
>   version. We don't as a rule install things like this globally as if it
>   was then updated and the API changed it would break everyone that
>   depended on its code.
>
> You would need to check the .inc file on the old server to confirm but
>   this code is probably the code in this GIT repo so it would be simple
>   enough to move in to the base application -
>   https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with pear. The [PEAR Net_GeoIP package](https://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP) has no `geoip.inc` file.

I guess that you have to put the source code of https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/ into `/usr/share/GeoIP/` directory.